# How to use R Studio View() function programatically / in a package

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to use the R Studio `View()` function programatically / in a package.

When I use `utils::View()`, a different viewer than the R Studio viewer (it appears to be the one built-in to `R`) is used, but if I use `View()` (without specifying where the function is exported from), issues come up during `R CMD CHECK`.

I checked the [R Studio cheatsheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjf6-fLu9PYAhWM3YMKHYijDjIQFggrMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rstudio.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F01%2Frstudio-IDE-cheatsheet.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3A-zVXttIDhihgp5nCk8_d), but this did not show whether / from where the R Studio `View()` is exported.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you would like to accomplish? Dummy code please.

Comment: Sure, something like `View(readr::read_lines(script_filename))`

Comment: Here, I'm trying to make it easier to view a script which is automatically generated by a function (and then run). The idea is folks may want to peak under the hood easily.

Comment: That's an interesting question of `utils::View()` vs `View()` I wouldn't know why, will have to see....

Comment: Agree. Yeah, it's not evident how to refer to [R Studio's] `View()`

Comment: It's also not clear to me how to find out!

Comment: I advise you to look at the source code of `View()`. It looks likes you may be to adjust it from within some related C/C++ function

Comment: It may be that utils::View in Rstudio is different that that of base R.  you should see some thing like `<environment: namespace:utils>` at the end of the print out when you type `View` in R console.   As an aside, suggesting that the user use the `View()` function to view feels like over-optimization.  Personally, I'd only go as far as to provide a print method and call it a day.

Comment: Printing it is a nice idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RStudio replaces the utils::View function with their own function when it starts up.  Their source is

```
function (...) 
.rs.callAs(name, hook, original, ...)
<environment: 0x1036a6dc0>
```

You can't just copy this into your package, because it depends on things in that environment, and there's no way for your package to get it.

However, you can do this:

```
myView <- function(x, title)
  get("View", envir = as.environment("package:utils"))(x, title)
```

and export `myView` from your package.  If you run this in RStudio, you'll get their function, if you run it anywhere else, you'll get the regular one.