# How to invoke R Studio View() function "tear-off" in an R script in R Studio?

Tags: r, rstudio

RStudio enables a user to invoke ("tear-off") a "Source Window" which displays a data frame, R code, and so on in a separate window from the RStudio panes.  I am writing an R script that I want to display multiple data frames across several monitors without the user having to manually "tear-off" a View() pane.

I can invoke a Source Window that appears in the RStudio IDE through `as.environment("package:utils")$View`.  Such a Source Window is not in a "torn-off" state, however.

Any suggestions on how to invoke a "torn-off" Source Window through an R script running in RStudio?

This question is related to [How to use R Studio View() function programmatically / in a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48234850/how-to-use-r-studio-view-function-programatically-in-a-package) and [Make RS View open in a new window automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49062761/make-rs-view-open-in-a-new-window-automatically?rq=1)

Comment: I'm glad to hear you are working on this. You might consider posting about this on the RStudio forums. The dev team seems to be pretty good about answering questions there. I was considering doing that eventually.